# Why Use pyopencl.array.Array

Tags: numpy, opencl, gpgpu, pyopencl

PyOpenCL has two ways of creating an OpenCL buffer:

`pyopencl.Buffer` takes a numpy array and turns it into a buffer.

`pyopencl.array.Array` takes a numpy array and turns it into a PyOpenCL array - an object that can be still be edited like a numpy array, but provides a buffer when you call `.data` on it.

Is there a performance/function reason to choose one or the other?  Or should I just choose the one that makes my code more readable?

Comment: Just saw your post and noticed that you didn't get any feedback. What did you end up doing? Did you discover a performance difference?

Comment: My guess is that these two ways of doing things are about the same in terms of performance.  The same data structures exist in both and the same operations occur on those structures.  pyopencl.array.Array is more readable - but less explicit about what it is actually doing.

Comment: When I try it, I do not get any significant performance differences.